# C# Wait for async operation to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, worker

I'm wondering what the best approach might be for what I'm trying to do. My application has a button that starts a background download operation, and then performs some actions dependent on the downloaded files.

It's like a "The game will begin shortly once necessary data is downloaded" situation, where the user may still use the main form.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //execute some code

    Downloader.RunWorkerAsync(files); //this worker reports progress to the main form

    while (Downloader.IsBusy)
        Application.DoEvents();

    //execute some more code
}
```

I'm aware that doing it that way is not good at all.

I cannot execute the download code synchronously, because the main form needs to remain responsive during the download operation.
I also cannot put the final code into the download completed event, as it is used by many other areas of the program and must remain a "generic" download system.

So, is there a way to do what I want? I do not have any experience with other async methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `BackgrounWorker` you must configure it properly. BW has `RunWorkerCompleted` event to which you must subscribe to handle completion of you async work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use asynchronous programming features of the .net 4.5 framework (`await` and `async`).

refer to [async programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: If I use .NET 4.5 features and try to run the application on a PC with an earlier .NET version, does it not work? The majority of users of this program are on 3.0 - 4.0